# Can I make multiple running instances of the same Windows program have different icons for switching

Tags: windows, icons

Running on Win7 I've got multiple instances of the BASH shell open, doing different things.

When I switch windows with ALT-TAB I can't distinguish between them. They all say "Git Bash" and they all have the same icon. So I've got to open them in sequence to get the one I want.

No problem when I am toggling between two windows, but it's annoying when I want to find one that I have not opened recently.

I might be able to do this by creating multiple instances of the shell .exe and putting a different icons in each, but that is somewhat restricting.

Is there something closer to what I'd want to do possible.

Comment: This is how Jeff solves it: http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0128776025bf970c-pi

Comment: Git wasn't meant to run on Windows. This is just karma—accept it!

Answer (score 1):

I had same problems and did some investigations here :)
Probably my [blog post](http://sparethought.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/troubleshooting-git-bash-icon-replaced-standard-cmd-exes-one/) will help you

The solution is to make several shortcuts for your shell and set different icons in their properties.